# How to change dynamic streaming URLs due to expiration (via CloudFront)

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront, osmf

So an issue with using CloudFront and OSMF is that each stream eventually expires (10 minutes in my case) and it leads to a NetStream.Failed event. Is there a way to dynamically change a video's dynamic streaming resource without causing havoc and resuming playback as normal?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using secure dynamic streaming. The normal dynamic stream does not cause this behavior. 
You should use a secure streaming plugin (like the akamai advancedstreamingplugin).

Or have you found another way to achieve this?